# How do I do a rectangular selection for the /tp command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working on a project that requires the /tp command (teleportation command). I wondered if there was a way to only teleport *every* player (real player and NPC players, such as a villager or any mobs) in a precise *rectangular* selection instead of a block radius selection. 
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rectangular selection"?

Comment: (@e means everything) /tp @e x y z

Comment: @Unionhawk, what I mean by "rectangular selection" is because when do the /tp command, we can do by the radius (for ex: r=5, it detect every entities in a radius of five blocks), but I didn't knew how to to detect entities that are, like for ex., in a rectangular area. For summary: _What I mean by here is "in a rectangular area"_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delta parameters (`dx`, `dy`, `dz`) state the number of blocks away from the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters to look for a target.

For example, the following teleports players starting from an origin of 10, up to 5 blocks in the X direction, 20 blocks in the Y, and 3 blocks in the Z.

The `team` parameter will throw out all non-living entities. Note that the selection will include armor stands, so that has been specifically excluded. If you're using teams, you may need to adjust usage (as the following only teleports those that aren't on a team):

```
/tp @e[x=10,y=10,z=10,dx=5,dy=20,dz=3,type=!ArmorStand,team=] 0 10 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only need it for making every players in my machine move each time it move of 1 block. It is because I don't want to make everyone in the server or world move of 1 block that I posted this question :)